# Continuity of Functions in Sets

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $X=Y\cup Z$. If $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is continuous such that $f|Y$ and $f|Z$ are also continuous then $f$ is continuous at all points $a \in Y \cap Z$.

So what I want to prove is that if $f$ is continuous in $Y \cup Z$, then it will also be in $Y \cap Z$.

The way I thought to solve was by contradiction, that is, if f is not continuous in a point $a \in Y \cap Z$, it could come to be that it is not continuous in $a \in Y$ or $a \in Z$, what would contradict the hypothesis, since if $f$ is continuous in $f|Y$ or $f|Z$, means that $f$ is continuous in $a \in Y$ or $a \in Z$, respectively.

Could someone help me complete?

Comment: "Continuous in a set" means : continuous at every point of the set. Therefore, if a function is continuous on a set $A$, it is continuous on every set included in $A$.

Comment: of course @TheSilverDoe